# Why does Titanium Alloy have so many leaks?

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, titanium, titanium-alloy

Why does instruments using the leaks tool show so many leaks and then crash after about three leak detection cycles?

That cannot be normal ?

The app I am testing on has one index window with one label in it which, on click opens another window which on click closes itself again.

No big deal yet it seems to have leaks ?
the first detection says 72 new leaks
the second then 8 new leaks ... ?

Does anyone know why this might be ?

Thanks for your help trying to get my head around this

[image]

Comment: this is not normal. If you app is so simple please show the code and also tell us the SDK version you are using please.

Answer (score 0):

Having developed apps with Titanium for 8 years now this doesn't look anything like it should. Whenever leaks are found by the community it usually is quickly fixed by the dev team. That said, it is very rare leaks are found.

Most memmory leaks are developer generated. For example if you create references to UI elements outside the controller it is in you will have to clean up the reference to that UI element to let garbage collection handle it. Garbage collection cannot trigger if you didn't free the components up.

I will not be able to help you further besides the above as you have not provided any relevant information like SDK version, code that causes it etc. You might've stumbled upon a real memory leak but chances are you're not freeing up resources.

Comment: Yes sorry for not adding more info I was in a hurry

SDK Version is 7.5.0.v20180824022007

I am using the journal alloy template found on GitHub and have not modified it
https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy/tree/master/samples/apps/models/journal

Persistent bytes goes up to around 26MiB from the beginning
Doesn't that seem quite high ?

Comment: 26mb for start is quite good as it needs to put a JScore into memory among the SDK and other things. It shouldn't leak though